# seunjeon elasticsearch plugin for es 7.9.1

Tags: elasticsearch, plugins

I need to build Elasticsearch seunjeon plugin for Elasticsearch 7.9.1. The codebase at https://bitbucket.org/eunjeon/seunjeon/src/master/elasticsearch/ allows building the plugin for Elasticsearch 6.x. I am not sure how to build the plugin targeted towards 7.9.x.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently patched seunjeon for Elasticsearch 7. I think it'll help you a lot.

https://github.com/likejazz/seunjeon-elasticsearch-7

And I've also uploaded version 7.9.1 for you. so you can easy to install as shown below:

```
$ bin/elasticsearch-plugin install https://github.com/likejazz/seunjeon-elasticsearch-7/releases/download/7.9.1/analysis-seunjeon-7.9.1.zip
```